# Why index variable not display indexing in *ngFor loop in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, ngfor

If we want to display the index of ng-repeat in angular 1,

we use the following code

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
 <ul>
  <li>Index: {{$index+1}}</li>
  <li>Car Name:{{car.name}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Now when the same I implement in Angular 2, it is not displaying index value

```
<div *ngFor="#car of cars">
 <ul>
      <li>Index: {{index+1}}</li>
      <li>Car Name:{{car.name}}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

But when I add #i = index in *ngFor, it suddenly display index value

```
 <div *ngFor="#car of cars; #i = index">
     <ul>
          <li>Index: {{i+1}}</li>
          <li>Car Name:{{car.name}}</li>
         </ul>
 </div>
```

As both 2nd and 3rd code are same, but it work only when we declare the local variable and assign the variable to index.

Such an ambiguous thing.

Will any one help to understand better use of this ?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd code aren't the same?

Answer (score 2):

reference this:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

```js
<div *ngFor="#car of cars;let i=index">
     <ul>
          <li>Index: {{i+1}}</li>
          <li>Car Name:{{car.name}}</li>
         </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars; index as i">
  <ul>
    <li>Index: {{i}}</li>
    <li>Car Name:{{car.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
    {{i}}
</li>
```

**[DEMO PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/7BEnvZWr6vDBKS8Kd2Ai?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overriding of variables within your template. There is also the `odd`, `even`, `first`, `last` variable you can assign in the `*ngFor` loop. But if you had a component like this:

```
@Component({..})
export class SillyComponent {

   public first: number;
   public last: number;
   public index: number;

}
```

There is no way to access these from within the `*ngFor` loop if they are immediately assigned by the templating engine. This is one of the reasons why you have to declare them first explicitly inside your template. Besides that, it also gives you better IDE hinting and readability of your code

I also see you are using a very very old notation. You should use the `let` keyword in templates now to declare variables:

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index">
   <ul>
        <li>Index: {{i+1}}</li>
        <li>Car Name:{{car.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP is using the beta version of angular

Comment: @echonax Like i said, very old notation :) over a year ago they changed this (since `2.0.0-beta.17`). Probably some none updated tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use index is that it is in the local scope of ng-for

```
<div *ngFor="#car of cars; #i = index">
```

# or let denotes local variables , index over here is the local variable for ng for so outside ng for it is not defined so it is not accessible, to access this data we use local variable from current scope to refer local scope of ng for. So for this specific reason we need to refer using any local variable.

Comment: $index in angular version was a referernce variable that was used to refer index of ng repeat. Even in the earlier version it is index itself but $index was predefined reference to index. Check line number 348 of https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js

Answer (score 0):

Your **1st code snippet** is angular 1.x `ng-repeat`, which creates `new child scope`, So `$index` is the property of `new child scope` which is exposed and you can use directly. Like you use any `$scope` property of controller without `prefixing $scope` to it in html.

now in **angular2**, In this case there is no separate scope, just `this` of javascript.

Also, angular2+ is written in `typescript` So `ngFor export` the variable `index`*(also other properties like odd, even , first, last)*, to consume it you need to declare some local variable.

`ngFor` creates a block like `for loop` of javascript. and `i` creates a template local variable to get the index of the array.

also, use `let` instead of `#`, changed since [**2.0.0-beta.17**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28)

Here are some good articles for comparison. [link](http://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/ng-repeat-ngfor/), [link](https://namitamalik.github.io/NgRepeat-vs-ngFor/)